# How can I show a facebook box modal seconds after a visitor hits my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I need to show a facebook box with like and share options on my website. The box should pop-up 5 seconds after the visitor hit the page and should not disappear unless Like, Share or Close is pressed.

Moreover, I would like to show the box only to those who did not like the page yet (if they are logged on facebook) and also only to those who, based on their IP addresses were not shown the box in the last 30 days.

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly, I'm pretty sure this kind of behaviour is against FB rules. Secondly, please don't do this. All it does is annoy your visitors. How is someone supposed to know if they enjoy your site in the 2 seconds before the stupid FB popup appears? Your bounce rate will skyrocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we don´t need to discuss how to open a popup with HTML, and showing the box only to those who did not see it in the last 30 days would be easy too > just store the IP of every visitor. BUT: If you want to store IPs and timestamps, you need to tell the user about it (privacy and stuff). You can´t just store whatever you want. Also, IPs can change, so this would actually be senseless to implement.

Let´s get to the main point: Showing the popup only to those who did not like the Page. First of all, you are not allowed to "incentivize a person to like or share something", as you can read in the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). That being said, you would need to authorize a user with the `user_likes` permission in order to check if he liked a specific Facebook page already. That permission needs to get approved by Facebook before you can use it for everyone, and Facebook will definitely not approve it for that case.

There are other ways by using by using [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.2) to subscribe to the click on a Like button, but that would be pointless since you can´t detect it for new users or returning ones. You can store a cookie, but that would be just for returning ones.

**TL;DR:** There would be a lot of obstacles and it would never really work 100%. Also, as Rory McCrossan already commented, it´s a very bad idea and annoying for visitors.

Comment: Thank all of you guys! You made me change my mind!